# AngularJS - directive scope not setting ng-class on element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QJqICyTrdvAZvSjQ5Gi9)

I have a table of data:

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-class="dndElemClass" drag-and-drop>
  ...
</table>
```

My goal is to give the table a drop shadow by assigning `$scope.dndElemClass = 'on-drag-enter'` on the element's `ondragenter` event listener:

```
.on-drag-enter {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
    ...
}
```

The `onDragEnter` directive is as follows:

```
directive('dragAndDrop', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.dndElemClass = '';
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope.$watch('currentFolder.canUpload', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue && Modernizr.draganddrop && window.File) {
                    elem[0].ondragenter = function(evt) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.dndElemClass = 'on-drag-enter';
                        });
                    };
                    elem[0].ondragleave = function(evt) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.dndElemClass = '';
                        });
                    };
                    elem[0].ondrop = function(evt) {
                        ...
                    };
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Despite assigning the value of `$scope.dndElemClass` in the `ondragenter` and `ondragleave` event listeners, the `<table>` doesn't appear to be recognizing the value and assigning the class as no dropshadow appears.

Thus far I've tested that it does recognize the value if I set the class in the controller property of the directive where I have it assigned to blank in the above code, so I know it will accept it from the directive.  With the class set in the controller as a test, if I trigger the `ondragenter` listener, it removes the class.  I've also confirmed that the `$scope.$apply()` is properly assigning the value of `scope.dndElemClass` with logging, but for whatever reason, when set in the event listeners's `$scope.$apply()`, the table's `ng-class` attribute won't recognize the variable assignment and thinks it's empty.

---

**UPDATE:**
As per Josh's comment, I cleaned up the code so that I didn't have to `$apply` the variable assignment in the event listener callbacks.

```
directive('dragAndDrop', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.dndElemClass = '';
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope.$watch('currentFolder.canUpload', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue && Modernizr.draganddrop && window.File) {
                    elem.bind('dragenter', function(evt) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        $scope.dndElemClass = 'on-drag-enter';
                    });
                    elem.bind('dragleave', function(evt) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        $scope.dndElemClass = '';
                    });
                    elem.bind('drop', function(evt) {
                        //...
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Still no luck.  I can verify it is executing the callbacks with logging, but no luck on getting the variable assignment to be recognized by the table's `ng-class` attribute.

---

**UPDATE 2:**  I am even more confused after reading through [AngularJS's documentation on ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).  To me, I thought it was as simple as setting the name(s in an array) of the classes you want to a variable in the current controller's (or in my case, the directive's) `$scope`, then specify that variable's name like you would anywhere else in the element's `ng-class=""` attribute.  But as I'm reading, it seems like it's more much complicated as people are using [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass#comment-758028928) or [toggling the class name(s)](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/nFcLh/).

Using the idea of toggling, I forked [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U6EtAEOBsWLIduhoMUma) to recreate the situation setting `$scope.dndElemClass` to a boolean value based on whether the user triggers `dragenter` or `dragleave`.  I also included `$scope.$apply()` for good measure, as I am finding that I don't understand the advantage of `angular.bind()` over `.addEventListener` or `.ondragenter = function() {};`.  Regardless, none of this has caused the table's class to get set as I would expect it to.

Comment: Why are you leaving AngularJS World to run an event only to try to re-enter it to set a scope variable? Why not simply use `elem.bind('dragenter', function () {...})`? Try simplifying your code and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Wasn't familiar with Angular's .bind().  After cleaning it up and getting rid of the `$apply()`, still no luck.

Comment: It's probably a scope issue. Can you post a simple Plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: Sure thing, added a link at the top.

Comment: I am not using `ng-class` like you do. I do something like: `ng-class="{ondrag-nter:dndElemClass}">`. Let me know if this works for you so I can add a real answer explaining in more detail.

Comment: Looking over their (frankly downright horrendous) documentation on ngClass, I have to say I'm more confused than understanding of how ngClass works in AngularJS.  I thought in my case it was as simple as assigning a class name to a $scope variable and passing it along to the view to use in `ng-class="scopedVariable"`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still need an answer, but I might have fixed your plunk.

Inside the `CurrentFolder` controller, add

```
$scope.dndElemClass  = '';
```

Then wrap `$scope.dndElemClass` inside `$apply`.

```
$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.dndElemClass = 'on-drag-enter'; });
```

Check the [complete plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bjFMAaf6TjcQoUXD74x5) for a clearer picture.

[image]

Comment: this answer just fixed a similar issue I was having - setting a controller's scope.myVar from inside a directive. The ng-class was waiting for a change but nothing updated when the myVar changed. Wrapping it in that $apply was the trick! Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to set class in **scope** then use `class={{classVariable}}` !!!
This works for me.