# angular.bind() for 'drop' event listener not behaving properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Plunker demonstrating code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cvms35UyKOV1iwUmvLqN)

I have a `<div>` element with the directive `dragAndDrop` set as an attribute:

```
<div ng-class="divClass" drag-and-drop>Drop files here</div>
```

*(as a side, and less important note, ng-class is not behaving as expected, but that's a [separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419839/angularjs-directive-scope-not-setting-ng-class-on-element))*
What I would like is for users to drag and drop files from their desktop to the div.  Upon doing so though, I use `angular.bind()` to detect the drop event.  Of course once they drop, I call `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`, but the page continues on with redirecting the page regardless.  What am I doing wrong that would prevent the two aforementioned methods from executing?

`dragAndDrop` directive:

```
directive('dragAndDrop', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
      elem.bind('dragenter', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        // still can't get this one to behave:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/q/15419839/740318
        $scope.divClass = 'on-drag-enter';
      });
      elem.bind('dragleave', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $scope.divClass = '';
      });
      elem.bind('drop', function(e) {
        var droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
        // It's as though the following two methods never occur
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        if (droppedFiles.length > 0) {
          for (var i=0,ii=droppedFiles.length;i<ii;i++) {
            $scope.files.push(droppedFiles[i]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular doesn't know when event handlers you have registered are triggered, so you need to notify Angular that you've changed scope variables. You do that with the [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) function.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.divClass = 'on-drag-enter';
});
```

<s>When it comes to the drop handler you're correct--the statements after `var droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;` are never run because of the runtime error that statement results in.</s>

`e` is a jQuery event, whereas `dataTransfer` is a property on the actual DOM event. To fix the problem you need to access the original event through the `originalEvent` property.

```
var droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
```

**Update**

`e.originalEvent` is only needed if you have included jQuery before angular, but since you haven't done that in your plnkr, that solution was invalid, I apologize for that.

It seems like you need to opt in for drop support by [`preventDefault` of the dragover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover) (Perhaps this can be done in other events as well--haven't tested.)

```
elem.bind('dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uidw0XvRSRzzQrxMgwy5?p=preview).

Comment: Neither of those worked, for either issue.  I've updated the plunker to reflect your recommendations.  As for the `$scope.$apply()`, I presumed that was unnecessary given the `angular.bind()` method put on the element would keep scope, when using something such as `.addEventListener()` or `elem.ondrop = function()` would not.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: `$scope.$apply` (you missed the `$`) fixes the css class problems. (Gonna take a look at the other problem when I get home.)

Comment: Doh!  Good catch.  Oddly enough, I seemingly recall trying that before based off previous advice from elsewhere.  I must have either been making a mistake elsewhere or not trying it at all.  Regardless, thank you.  Looking forward to the ondrop solution.

Comment: @Scott, when a `bind()` callback function runs, it runs "outside" of Angular, because `bind()` just sets up normal JavaScript event binding -- hence the need for us to manually call `$apply()`.  It might be nice if Angular provided some kind of `bindApply()` or 'angularBind()` method that would automatically call `$apply()` for us after executing the callback function.

Comment: So that begs the question, why even use `angular.bind()`?  Formality?

Comment: You're not using '`angular.bind`' but their jqLite implementation (it's usually a good idea to include jQuery before Angular, so you get full jQuery support). `bind` (or `on` which is the 'new' syntax) is a good faqade around different browser implementations.

Comment: dragover... That's a new one.  Alas it does appear to solve the problem!  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: You don't have to set the dropEffect, but you do need to stop the dragover event, otherwise the drop event won't fire.